# Identify if at least one substring from a list exists in Pandas column/row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of several substrings that I'm needing to identify rows that have at least one of them in a column.  I have code that correctly identifies if one string appears, but I can't get it to identify the list.

```
df.Col1.str.contains('text')
```

Correctly returns a series.  However, what I really want is to use a list to identify one of many options and return a True if any of the options are included.

```
list1 = ['text','Text','third',fourth']
for item in list1:
    df.Col1.str.contains(item)
```

Returns four series which isn't good for my use.

I've also tried:

```
for item in list:
    if df.Col1.str.contains(item) == True:
        df['Check'] = 'True'
```

But it returns 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous'.

What do I need to change to get this to work on a list instead of a single string?

My end result for the new data frame column will be a value of 'True' if one of the options in the list and nothing if the string does not contain any of the list options.

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question, you can use the method any(), to obtain a single boolean value for a pandas series. It equates to a logical "or", i.e. it is true if any of the values in the series is true and false otherwise.
Secondly, you should not use "list" as a variable name, since it is a python built-in function that you overwrite, which is bad practice.
Thirdly, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by the line

```
df['Check'] = 'True'
```

since you are writing "True" in every line in column "Check" for every time the if-condition is true but I am going to assume that this is what you want.
Finally, instead of

```
if x == True:
     ...
```

you can use

```
if x:
    ...
```

Therefore, your code should look something like this:

```
list1 = ['text','Text','third','fourth']

for item in list1:
    if df.id.str.contains(item).any() == True:
        df['Check'] = 'True'
```

Comment: Slight correct, I'm not wanting to print 'True' on every row if something appears, I'm wanting to only print 'True' on rows where the item in List1 appears. 

Right now, this prints True on every row, even if one of the text items in list1 does not appear in the column.

Comment: In this case i would use the following approach:

df["Check"] = False;

for item in list1:
    df["Check"] = df["Check"] | df.is.str.contains(item);

making use of "|", which is a logical "or" working element-wise on a pandas series.